# How to use BeautifulSoup to get text that's in a react text wrapper?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Here's the HTML code, from Yahoo Finance

```
<p class="class="D(ib) W(47.727%) Pend(40px)">
   <!-- react-text: 561 -->
   "1601 Willow Road"
   <!-- /react-text -->
   <br>
   <!-- react-text: 563 -->
   "Menlo Park, CA 94025"
   <!-- /react-text -->
   <br>
   <!-- react-text: 565 -->
   "United States"
   <!-- /react-text -->
   <br>
   <a href="tel:6505434800" class="C($linkColor)">650 543 4800</a>
   <br>
   <a href="https://investor.fb.com" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank"
    class="C($linkColor)" title="">https://investor.fb.com</a>
</p>
```

I want to get the information strings individually, but my code at the moment returns
everything in a single line. This is what I have right now and what it returns:

```
soup.find('p', {'class':'D(ib) W(47.727%) Pend(40px)'}).text
```

returns

```
'1601 Willow RoadMenlo Park, CA 94025United States650 543 4800https://investor.fb.com'
```

Additionally, here's the link: https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/quote/FB/profile?p=FB

Comment: can you show us your expected output!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

To get the strings separated use ***[`stripped_strings`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#strings-and-stripped-strings)***:

```
list(soup.find('p', {'class':'D(ib) W(47.727%) Pend(40px)'}).stripped_strings)
```

or selected more specific:

```
list(soup.select_one('[data-reactid="7"] p').stripped_strings)
```

This will give you a list in same order as in html and you can pick elements by index:

```
['1601 Willow Road',
 'Menlo Park, CA 94025',
 'United States',
 '650 543 4800',
 'https://investor.fb.com']
```

Alternativ is ***[`.get_text('|').split('|')`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text)*** that would lead to the same result.